# How do I get area of an arbitrary shape using numerical integration?

Tags: numerical-methods, area

I would like to get area of an arbitrary shape (using numerical integration).

For instance like this:

[image: An arbitrary shape]

How do I get that using numerical integration?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planimeter

Comment: @MohammadReza Computer program...

Comment: Actually, this is a duplicate. The question has been asked before.

Comment: [Here's a bunch of them.](https://www.google.be/search?q=area+of+random+shape+site%3A+math.stackexchange.com&rlz=1C1SVEA_nlBE406BE406&oq=area+of+random+shape+site%3A+math.stackexchange.com&aqs=chrome..69i57.18558j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Break it up into smaller basic shapes. This will get you an approximation. The smaller your shapes, the better your approximation. One easy way to do this is to draw it on a grid and count the number of squares it covers. Partial covering of a square should still count.

[image]

For example consider the shape above. Draw a uniform grid over it. Each small square has an area $A$ which is easy to calculate. Now just count how many squares your shape covers (i.e. the dark red squares in the 3rd figure).I count 37. Thus the area of the complex shape is approximately $37*A$. The smaller you make A, the better your approximation will be.

This is particularly easy if you have a digital copy of the shape.

Answer (score 9):

Draw it on a paper, then cut with scissors and weight. Then divide by the weight of the unit square.

Comment: Most interesting method I have ever heard of :D

Comment: What do you mean by `weight`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight